# Java selenium find element with xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

all I'm delevoping a web app and I need to find a specific element but I can't find it out with my xpath.
This is the html code where I'm trying to find the element

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="details">
            <label>Name</label>
        </th>
        <td class="data">
            <div id="...">
                <div id="..."></div>
                <input id="..." type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
 ..........
</table>
```

I successfully found it but when I noticed that the ids are autogenerated I got stuck. I tried to solve this problem finding the label which contains the text 'Name' and then finding the siblings but nothing. This is my xpath:

```
//*[text()[contains(.,'Name')]]/../following-sibling::td
```

Comment: Try out this `//input[@type='text']` and you misspelled `Name` as `Nome` in your xpath.

Comment: The classes are also changing? like details, data

Comment: I forgot to say that in this website there are multiple input tags, however also the class are changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using below `xpath` :-

```
String xpath = "(.//label[text() = 'Name']/following::input)[1]";
```

Or

```
String xpath = ".//label[text() = 'Name']/../following-sibling::td//input";
```

Or

```
String xpath = "(.//input[preceding::label[text() = 'Name'])[1]";
```

Or

```
String xpath = ".//input[ancestor::td[preceding-sibling::th/label[text() = 'Name']]]";
```

You can use anyone of these above `xpath` to find desire input element as below :-

```
browser.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
```

Answer (score 0):

try below xpath

```
"//label[contains(.,'Name')]/../following-sibling::td/div/input[@type='text']"
```

Assuming that the DOM structure remains constant.