# Selenium findElement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to find element in the element. I mean 
for example I find  `webDriverWrapper.findElement(locatorManager.getLocator("user.root.element"))` this element, how, I would like to search some element starting from this element. I do this one:

```
webDriverWrapper.findElement(locatorManager.getLocator("user.root.element")).findElement(locatorManager.getLocator("popup.cancel.link")).click();
```

But, as I understand the search starts at the beginner of document.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319847/java-selenium-find-element-with-xpath

Comment: The search is relative to the current element.

Answer (score 0):

Chained `findElement` **is not searching from beginning every time** unless you explicitly say so (for example, if you use xpath starting with `//`).

Answer (score 0):

Find element xpathArgs, site name url, web driver

```
public List<WebElement> findElement(String xpathArgs, String site, WebDriver driver) {
        driver.get(site);

        List<WebElement> find_elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathArgs));
        return find_elements;
    }
```